# Gradle takes long (40 seconds) even with no code change (flutter)

Tags: flutter, gradle

I use VS code and building a sample app. I have a 6-core AMD processor (FX-6300) with 32 GB RAM, and an SSD. I've just been unable to get builds fast.

This is my current gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3096m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.daemon=true 
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Even with no change building (F5: Start Debuging) the build takes 40 seconds.

gradlew --version shows

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3      

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7-27)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code is or why its taking too much to build as you mention no info about .

But in case your building multiple projects adding `org.gradle.parallel=true` will help a lot .

And assuming your build will need `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M`  then the next time all the details will be cached so it will spend less time to run , so giving more to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx~` might help as well .

An increase in the memory size will help you to hold caches of your bigger build and thus improving the performance.

Comment: https://scans.gradle.com/s/3x3na2dqoaxcs has the scan results (took > 20 minutes and even aborted)

Comment: with these changes you suggested, (re)build is taking 10 seconds (25%) lower:
```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8000m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.daemon=true 
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: Great , glad this helped .